# Filter JSON Data with multiple record IDs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, json, filter, match

[Based on Subhaze's Function named "filterScore"](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4391119/revisions)... is just working fine if there is single value needs to be passed to `KEY`... But my question is what if there are **multiple values** needs to be parsed?

like for example there is a key named `brand_id` which is integer.. And I want to parse those data which have `brand_id = 1 OR 3 OR 5 OR 7` (multiple) in JQuery `RegExp`, `Filter`, `Match`... Please help me out with this guyz!!

How can I do this??

Would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As brands id are a list and not a pattern you can modify the filter function to accept `brand_id` as an array instead of a `regex`. New filter function would be

```
function filterStore(dataStore, filter) {
    return $(dataStore).filter(function(index, item) {
        for( var i in filter ) {
            if(filter[i] instanceof Array){   
              if($.inArray(parseInt(item[i],10),filter[i]) == -1)
                 return null;
              else
                 continue;                  
            }
           if( ! item[i].toString().match( filter[i] ) ) return null;
        }
        return item;
    });
}
```

Then you can put all your brand id's in a array like this

```
var filter = {
    "brand_id": [1,2,3],
    "productname": new RegExp('(.*?)', 'gi'),
    "price": new RegExp('.*?', 'gi')
};
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/bsaJm/4/)

Comment: Thanks Joy!!! It worked for me.. But what happens.. When we match for brand_id 1,2 or 3... it also returns records contains 11, 12, or 13 or even 33, 22, 11.. as it matches 1,2 or 3 in key named "brand_id".. how to solve this??

Comment: You can better pass an array for `brand_id` as you have a set of values to check for rather than a `pattern`, so I have modified the filter function where you can pass an array for `brand_id`, check here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/bsaJm/4/

Comment: Hey Joy... Thanks a lot man.. you made my day.. :) But would like to ask if there is any other option without looping through all the records?? as it takes long time to process for large amount of records..