# Filter Hierarchical JSON Data with multiple record IDs in jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, json, filter, match

With Reference of below links:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4391119/revisions

[Filter JSON Data with multiple record IDs in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870334/filter-json-data-with-multiple-record-ids-in-jquery)

What if there is a Hierarchical Data in JSON.. I've tried making modification in that filterStore function.. but not being succeeded. Can you help me with that??

Current filterStore is like this:

```
var filter = {
    "brand_id": [1,2,3],
    "productname": new RegExp('(.*?)', 'gi'),
    "price": new RegExp('.*?', 'gi')
};

function filterStore(dataStore, filter) {
    return $(dataStore).filter(function(index, item) {
        for( var i in filter ) {
            if(filter[i] instanceof Array){   
              if($.inArray(parseInt(item[i],10),filter[i]) == -1)
                 return null;
              else
                 continue;                  
            }
           if( ! item[i].toString().match( filter[i] ) ) return null;
        }
        return item;
    });
}
```

but json response is something like this:

```
[
    {
      "brandInfo": {
          "brand": "Lg",
          "productname": "Microwave",
      },
      "prodInfo": {
          "size": "1.5 ltr",
          "price": 200,
          "color": "black"
      },
      "Category": "Electronic",
      "shop": "Walmart"
    }
    {
      "brandInfo": {
          "brand": "Samsung",
          "productname": "Microwave",
      },
      "prodInfo": {
          "size": "1.5 ltr",
          "price": 250,
          "color": "Ivory"
      },
      "Category": "Electronic",
      "shop": "Walmart"
    }
    {
      "brandInfo": {
          "brand": "Toshiba",
          "productname": "Microwave",
      },
      "prodInfo": {
          "size": "1.6 ltr",
          "price": 310,
          "color": "Silver"
      },
      "Category": "Electronic",
      "shop": "Walmart"
    }
    {
      "brandInfo": {
          "brand": "Hitachi",
          "productname": "Microwave",
      },
      "prodInfo": {
          "size": "1.5 ltr",
          "price": 280,
          "color": "black"
      },
      "Category": "Electronic",
      "shop": "Walmart"
    }
]
```

Joy, Can you help me set filters for hierarchical data like this?? new function filterStore?

Comment: use jLinq .. makes working with data object a dream

Answer (score 0):

Start by re-writing the filter to reflect the nested structure.

```
var filter = {
    "brandInfo": {
        "brand_id": [1,2,3]
    },
    "prodInfo": {
        "productname": new RegExp('(.*?)', 'gi'),
        "price": new RegExp('.*?', 'gi')
    }
};
```

Now you can write the filter code like this (just adding a nested loop to cycle through the outer properties like *brandInfo*).

```
function filterStore(dataStore, filter) {
    return $(dataStore).filter(function(index, item) {
        for( var prop in filter ) {
            if (item[prop] == null) return null;
            for( var i in prop ) {
                if (item[prop][i] == null) return null;
                if(filter[prop][i] instanceof Array){  
                    if($.inArray(parseInt(item[prop][i],10),filter[prop][i]) == -1) return null;
                    else continue; 
                }
                if( ! item[prop][i].toString().match( filter[prop][i] ) ) return null;
            }
        }
        return item;
    });
}
```

This should work as far as the data structure in your example goes.  But keep in mind, this code assumes that your filter contains only second-level nested properties.  For a more general solution to filtering nested properties, you'd need to put your filter logic in a separate function and use it recursively.